# Can't push a project to Heroku. Fingerprint problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I try to push a git project to heroku, it gives me an error -

> Your key with fingerprint xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx is not authorized to access my_heroku_app.

I've tried almost anything and everything I found on the internet - adding keys, uploading, removed every key and then retried. I've checked there are no multiple accounts. I've also checked the .git/config file to see if the project name is accurate.

I noticed that after I delete the known_hosts file and try to push the project, it says -

> The authenticity of host 'heroku.com (50.19.85.132)' can't be established.
>   RSA key fingerprint is *some.random.fingerprint.
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
>   Warning: Permanently added 'heroku.com,50.19.85.154' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
>    !  Your key with fingerprint *my.original.configured.fingerprint* is not authorized to   access first-app.
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

This is interesting because that is not my fingerprint. The one I have in ib_rsa.pub is different from the one that heroku tries to use. I did a heroku keys and I see only one key (the one it's supposed to use.)
I have no idea where it's picking this weird key from. Any suggestions will help. Thanks!

Comment: Did you already do `heroku login`?

Comment: I figured, just checking

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution.

in .git/config, changed the project name in [remote "heroku"] to the name given by heroku.

Answer (score 4):

to avoid Fingerprint problems just enter

`$ heroku git:remote -a your-heroku-app-name`

(my case: $ heroku git:remote -a blooming-plateau-75741)

and follow with `$ git push heroku master`

Answer (score 2):

For the beginning, should, as mentioned above -

> to avoid Fingerprint problems just enter

```
$ heroku git:remote -a your-heroku-app-name
```

Then, you need create a key again:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

And add to heroku:

```
heroku keys:add
```

And follow you can push:

```
$ git push branch_name:master
```