# Trouble pushing project to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am doing the Hartle Ruby on Rails Tutorial and this is my first time pushing a project to heroku and I'm trying to figure out what's going wrong..

```
$ heroku login
email
password
Could not find an existing public key 
Would you like to generate one? [y/n] <--- I hit enter which gave me..
Generating new SSH public key.
Uploading SSH public key /Users/myname/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... done
Authentication successful.
```

After that I go to the next command, heroku create, because I am already in the directory I want, "first_app"

```
$ heroku create
Creating immense-savannah-2464... done, stack is cedar
http://immense-savannah-2464.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:immense-savannah-2464.git  <--- this is not what Hartl gets in his tutorial so I don't know if this looks right or wrong.
```

After that I then try and push my project to heroku:

```
$ git push heroku master
The authenticity of host 'heroku.com (XX.XX.XX.XXX)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is Xb:XX:Xe:XX:Xe:cX:XX:XX:XX:fX:XX:Xc:Xf:cX:XX:ad.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? <--- I always hit "no" because I don't know if I should hit "yes." After I hit "no" it tells me that the host key verification failed!
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm stuck - any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269922/permission-denied-publickey-when-deploying-heroku-code-fatal-the-remote-end

Answer (score 0):

Have you already gone through [all the steps listed here?](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys)
You need to create a public/private key pair to deploy code to Heroku.

That post walks you through all the steps.

I found [this answer that might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755041/cant-push-a-project-to-heroku-fingerprint-problems). Try changing the project name in [remote "heroku"] to the name given by heroku in `.git/config`

#### Update

I just had exactly the same problem. I typed `yes` when it asked `Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?`, then it still wouldn't connect and returned `fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`.

I then ran `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, hit enter a few times and it worked.

This problem came up since I copied my Rails folder to a new computer. The rest of the heroku commands worked, only pushing didn't.

Comment: I have not! Would I get a different result than when I first generated a public key (look at the top under "heroku login")?

Comment: You need a public **and** private key in order to deploy. I would go through the steps and then see what happens.

Comment: Appreciate the heads up. I'll give that a try and see what happens.

Comment: Just tried the link you sent and generated a public key like it said at the top (not sure where/how I can create a private key)  and then tried the heroku login, heroku create, and git push heroku master commands. When I got to the "git push heroku master" command I got the same answer as I initially wrote above... Is it that I need a private key or need to hit "yes" to the "continue connecting" question above? Or something else..?

Comment: Look at my updated answer, also this might help https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-repository-ssh-fingerprints

Comment: Gotcha - just looked at the link you posted here and I guess I'm trying to figure out how to manually match the SSH key to the fingerprint so that I end up getting: $ git push heroku master
> The authenticity of host 'heroku.com (50.19.85.132)' can't be established.
> RSA key fingerprint is 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad.
> Matching host key fingerprint found in DNS.
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

Comment: Once I get "Matching host key fingerprint found in DNS" I think I should be good. That's the one line I'm missing in my initial post at the top! Just need to figure out how to actually match it..